# How to make a transaction from TAILS

Tags: offline, tor

I have been unable to find a way to make an ETH transaction from a temporary [TAILS](https://tails.boum.org/) device since the usual wallets such as MyCrypto does not seem to run there.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a BIP39 phrase for a wallet, and want to make a simple ETH
transaction, the steps that work on TAILS 4.18 are the following.

0. When starting TAILS, add an admin user.
1. Download a stand-alone version of https://github.com/iancoleman/bip39 and get the private key of the relevant address from your BIP39 phrase.
2. Set up an environment suitable for the https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py python package. The following actions should from the amnesia user terminal.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install python3-dev gcc
torsocks curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | torsocks python3
PATH=$PATH:/home/amnesia/.local/bin
torsocks pip install --upgrade pip setuptools web3
```

3. Edit the following python code as needed, i.e., replace the private key, destination address, amount to send, gas price ( https://ethgasstation.info ) and save it as `prepare_tx.py`:

```
from web3 import Web3
from web3.auto import w3

gas_price = Web3.toWei("<GAS_PRICE>", "gwei")
amount_now = Web3.toWei("<ETHER_TO_TRANSFER>", "ether")
to_address = "<RECEIVER_ADDRESS>"
private_key = "<SENDER_PRIVATE_KEY>"

for nonce in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]:
    gas = 21000
    gas_total = gas * gas_price
    tx_amount = amount_now - gas_total

    tx = {
        "chainId": 1,  # main ETH chain
        "nonce": nonce,
        "to": to_address,
        "value": tx_amount,
        "gas": gas,
        "gasPrice": gas_price,
    }

    signed = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, private_key)
    s = signed.rawTransaction
    s_ = "0x" + "".join(format(x, "02x") for x in s)
    print(f"nonce={nonce}")
    print(s_)
    print("-")
```

4. Run `prepare_tx.py` to get signed transaction strings with different nonces.
5. Copy and paste the signed transaction string to https://etherscan.io/pushTx . Try to paste the first, if that does not work paste the second etc.